# Preventing Refreshes of Tableau Extract

Tags: data-extraction, tableau-api

I have published some Tableau extracts which are pulled from Microsoft SQL server. The extracts are very large, and are scheduled for early in the morning only once a month. I would like to prevent anyone from accidentally refreshing these, even Site Administrator.

When I publish the Data Source, it says I need to embed the authorization for refreshing on a schedule. However now when I've embedded the credentials, any site admins can still select refresh. Is there any way to take that option away, and only allow Server Admins to manually refresh the data?